# Regex : Replace URL unless starts with src=

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm looking for a regular expression to use in Refex.Replace that allows me to append a url with link elements.
The idea is this:

```
http://www.tenforce.com => <a target='new' href='http://www.tenforce.com'>http://www.tenforce.com</a>
```

However, the regex is not allowed to do this when the URL is part of a html element, like for an image tag for example. So if we have for example:

```
<img src="http://www.tenforce.com/logo.jpg" />
```

It should not be converted using the regex.

The original regex that we used was this one:

```
@"(http|ftp|https):((\/\/)|(\\\\))[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?";
```

But this encodes every url it can find into the an a-tag. I don't want it to encode urls when they are prepended with src=\"

So I tried adding **[^(src=.)]** to it, but this results in normal urls no longer beeing transformed. it doesn't transform the image tags either though.

The code looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
        /// Extends the text with hyperlinks.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">The value.</param>
        /// <param name="workspaceId">The workspace id where the user is working in. Used when parsing the wiki links</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string ExtendWithHyperlinks(string value, int? workspaceId)
        {
            if (value == null) return null;

            const string UrlPattern = @"[^(src=.)](http|ftp|https):((\/\/)|(\\\\))[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?";
            const string FilePattern = @"(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\\w((\.*\w+)|( *\w+))*)+";

            value = Regex.Replace(value, UrlPattern, "<a target='new' href='$0'>$0</a>").Replace(":\\\\", "://");
            value = Regex.Replace(value, FilePattern, "<a target='new' href='file:///$0'>$0</a>");
            value = TemplateParser.Parse(value, workspaceId, Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase.Remove(0, 8))));
            return value;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably do it with a negative lookbehind

```
(?<!src=['"]?)(http|ftp|https):...
```

Comment: thanks, this solved the problem. Made a small adjustment though, replaced the **['"]** with just a .

Answer (score 0):

Effectively, this question is a dupe of many others on SO. The real answer is: [don't use Regex to deal with HTML/XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Use an dedicated HTML parser. [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) is great, and you won't have to slum it with a tool that is ill-suited to the job.

Comment: Valid, but applicable in this case. The text that is entered can be anything random typed by a user, and we need to convert it to valid HTML so it can be properly displayed. The problem however is when using a tool like ckeditor that automatically injects html in an RTF field, we need to be able to ignore HTML and still encode everything else to HTML

Comment: Fair enough, but downvote for sharing a common wisdom in what appeared to be an appropriate situation seems a little harsh.